# Compiling x265 with ffmpeg for Android and receiving errors

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compilation, hevc

Trying to compile x265 for use with arm64-v8a. After successuful build of x265 itself, I receive the following error when ffmpeg is about to compile:

```
require_pkg_config libx265 x265 x265.h x265_api_get
check_pkg_config libx265 x265 x265.h x265_api_get
test_pkg_config libx265 x265 x265.h x265_api_get
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/ffmpeg-pkg-config --exists --print-errors x265
check_func_headers x265.h x265_api_get -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib -lx265
test_ld cc -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib -lx265
test_cc -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test.c
    1   #include <x265.h>
    2   #include <stdint.h>
    3   long check_x265_api_get(void) { return (long) x265_api_get; }
    4   int main(void) { int ret = 0;
    5    ret |= ((intptr_t)check_x265_api_get) & 0xFFFF;
    6   return ret; }
END /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test.c
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang -DANDROID -fpic -fpie -march=armv8-a --sysroot=/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/sysroot -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -DANDROID -fpic -fpie -march=armv8-a -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/vpx/android/arm64-v8a/include -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x264/android/arm64-v8a/include/x264 -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/lame/android/arm64-v8a/include -DANDROID -fpic -fpie -march=armv8-a --static -mcpu=cortex-a57 -std=c11 -fPIE -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib -c -o /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test.o /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test.c
clang60: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/bin/aarch64-linux-android-clang -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -march=armv8-a -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/sysroot -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/vpx/android/arm64-v8a/lib -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x264/android/arm64-v8a/lib -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/lame/android/arm64-v8a/lib -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -march=armv8-a -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/sysroot -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now --static --sysroot=/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/sysroot -mcpu=cortex-a57 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -fPIE -pie -I/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/include/x265 -L/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib -o /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test /tmp/ffconf.xKyjnplW/test.o -lx265 -lgcc
clang60: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib/libx265.a when searching for -lx265
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/jni/x265/android/arm64-v8a/lib/libx265.a when searching for -lx265
/root/ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg-android-1.6.3/toolchain-android/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -lx265
clang60: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ERROR: x265 not found using pkg-config
```

I use ffmpeg 4.1.3 and the latest version of x265 sources. I use [this](https://github.com/cmeng-git/ffmpeg-android) project to compile and I have succeeded when building without x265. I compile on Debian Buster x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the scripts from [this](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) project that uses all latest NDK and ffmpeg together with every latest library, in order to create an ffmpeg binary. It works pretty well on my device and by modifying a bit, I got a static ffmpeg as well. I only needed to add 2 extra native libraries to my app for it to work. It even uses all CPU features so it is the fastest solution for mobiles.